# Traveling to the Dominican Republic with a Mexican passport/US resident card

Tags: visas, passports, dominican-republic

I am a teacher in the USA, taking students on a trip to the Dominican Republic. I have one student who has a Mexican passport as well as a permanent Rlresident card for the U.S. Will she be ok to travel to/from the Dominican Republic? Does she need another visa besides the tourist visa? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Visa policy of the Dominican Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Dominican_Republic), citizens of Mexico do not require a visa to enter the Dominican Republic (same as for US citizens).

Your student should have no paperwork problems on the trip and of course should bring both her Mexican passport *and* her US Permanent Resident card.

Note also that:

> As of 1 January 2018 visitors to Dominican Republic are no longer obliged to purchase a tourist card as this fee is now incorporated into airfare.